# How to get Tomcat upload/download speed with JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, tomcat8

Is there any way to get Tomcat upload and download traffic using Java and JMX?

Comment: There are "requestBytesReceived", "requestBytesSent", "bytesReceived" and "bytesSent" exposed on `Catalina/RequestProcessor/xxx/HttpRequestX`, there is also a `Catalina/GlobalRequestProcessor/xxx`

Comment: Can you show me some example code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat version = ?

If you ask about the count of bytes transferred, then yes. The detailed status page in the Manager web application shows that information and it obtains it via JMX.

You can look into org.apache.catalina.manager package classes StatusManagerServlet and StatusTransformer for the actual source code.

If you ask about transfer rate, if I remember correctly there is no such information. It can also be defined in different ways, as it differs across clients.

You can write your own Filter or Valve or AccessLogValve to perform such calculations and expose via JMX.

You can also analyze an access log file.

Comment: I need this information about Tomcat 8. Can you show me some code example please?